# html table right aligned has invisible part on the left of screen

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

I have a html table. Its right aligned. I have a table within it with fields. But when my chrome browser displays the table some portion of table (leftmost) is cropped in the left, ie its leftmost contents are outside of the screen.
The image of how my table looks like is here: https://yadi.sk/i/rR6rm8nuZsfXlA

How to make the right-aligned table to start at the beginning of the screen (on the left side) to see full table contents?

my code is:

```html
<table width=600 border="0" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>ID</strong></td>
          <td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
          <td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">
            <?php echo $rows2['a_id']; ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="18%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Name</strong></td>
          <td width="5%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
          <td width="77%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1">
            <?php echo $rows2['a_name']; ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the width of your outer table (600) does not fill the available space on your web page. If you want the table to start at the beginning of the screen, you could try removing the right alignment like this:

```html
<table width=600 border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>ID</strong></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
                    <td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows2['a_id']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="18%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Name</strong></td>
                    <td width="5%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
                    <td width="77%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows2['a_name']; ?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aligning a table to right has no meaning if your table width is bigger than screen width. You can try adding this to

```
<style>
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .mytable {
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: auto
  }
}
</style>
```

Assign the my table class to the table you want to align right and remove align=right from html.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the margin on the side and you can also use a percetage value for the auto resize of the table on screen narrowing